# polynomial pointer program error, scanner skipping inputs

Tags: c, pointers, polynomials

i wrote this program which calculates 8 polynomial degrees at value of x inputted by the user. the program runs, however once i enter the 8 polynomials it should allow me to enter the value of x however it skips, and shows me the output. i tried using floats and doubles in scanner function however that didn't work. any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void get_poly(double *coeff, int N);
double eval_poly(double *coeff, double base, int N);

int main(void)
{
    int N = 8;
    double res;
    double base = 0.0;
    double a[N];
    double *coeff;
    coeff = &a[0];

       printf("Enter the eight coeffecients: \n");
       scanf(" %d",&N);
       get_poly(coeff, N);

       printf("Enter x: \n");
       scanf(" %lf", &base);

       res=eval_poly(coeff, base, N);

       printf("Output: %f. \n",res); 


      return 0;
  }

void get_poly(double *coeff, int N)
{
   int i = 0;
   double placeholder;
   for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
   {
    scanf(" %lf", &placeholder);
    *coeff = placeholder;
    coeff++;
   }
}

double eval_poly(double *coeff, double base, int N)
{
   int i = 0;
   double res=0.0;

   for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
   res=res+coeff[i]*pow(base,i);

   return res;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanf skips second line of input, always](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958993/scanf-skips-second-line-of-input-always)

Answer (score 0):

A major problem is this definition in the `eval_poly` function:

```
double res=coeff[N];
```

Here the value of `N` is the size of the array passed to the function. Using it as an index will be *out of bounds* and lead to *undefined behavior*.

Same thing with the loop, where the condition `i <= N` will lead to you index the array out of bounds. ***And*** you will count the same element *twice*.

You should probably initialize `res` to zero.